# Compare all elements of a list of list Python

Tags: python, list

This is part of my list of list. My original list have more than 30 items:

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1.8, 1]]]
```

I need to compare all items of my `a`. I mean, if the first 9 items of my first item are equals to the first 9 items of the other item, `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9"`compare the item[1] of last item.

I call item2 as the others items of `a` list

```
lista = []
for item in a:
    print item
    >>> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]]
    >>> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1.8, 1]]
    if item[:1] == item2[:1]:
        if item[9][1] <= item2[9][1]:
            lista.append(item)
        if item[9][1] > item2[9][1]:
            lista.append(item2)


print lista
>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [1.8, 1]]
```

Comment: Use a container (like another list) for the first 9 items and you'll get this for free: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]]`

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements ?

Comment: I edited but I dont know how can I do it... @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Could you add the desired output? I'm unfortunately unable to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (kind-of) functional approach (I haven't tried this on Python 2.x):

```
from operator import itemgetter

def get_lista(a):
     if a and len(set(map(' '.join, map(str, map(itemgetter(0), a))))) == 1:
          return [a[0][0]] + [min(map(itemgetter(1), a), key=itemgetter(1))]
     return []

a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1.8, 1]]]
lista = get_lista(a)
print(lista) # [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1.8, 1]]
```

`get_lista(a)` will return an empty list, `[]`, if `a` is empty or if the first sub-item of each of the items of `a` do not match.

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]], [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1.8, 1]]]
print(get_lista(a)) # []
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `a[9][1]` is not the first item in that element, it is the second item, first item is `a[9][0]` as lists start at 0. Your issue was (amongst other things) the number of iterations you performed. Think about it, if `n` is the number of elements in the list, and for any given element `x` you are comparing it to every element in the list, then you should be iterating over the list `n^n` times. Whereas `for item in a: ...` only iterates over the list `n` times.

```
# our list of lists whom have the same first element and last item
lista = []
a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1.8, 1]]]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for y in range(len(a)):
        # lets check if the first element in each array is the same.
        if a[i[:1]] == a[y[:1]]:
            # if we got here then the first elements must be the same so lets compare second item of the last elements
            if a[i[-1]][1] == a[y[-1]][1]:
                # if we got here then the 2nd item of the last elements must be the same.
                lista.append(a[i] + a[y])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Soloution**

```
a = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[0.4, 3]],[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],[1.8, 1]]]

lista = []
for item in a:
    for i in range(0, len(a)): #changed loop method
        if item[0] == a[i][0]:
            if item[1][1] <= a[i][1][1]: #changed to item[1] of last set
                lista.append(item)
            elif item[1][1] > a[i][1][1]:
                lista.append(a[i])

print(lista)
```

**Output**

```
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/9$ python3 help.py
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0.4, 3]], [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1.8, 1]]]
(xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/9$
```

This was fun very fun!

So each `item` has a set of `item`'s in it, first we needed to compare the `item[0]`'s to all the `item[0]`'s but only once, so I compared `item[0]` (1, 2...) to all the `item[0]`'s using `a[i][0]`. If `item[0] == a[i][0]` , then we can compare the next sets. <strike>Next we compare `item[1][0]` to `a[i][1][0]` (.04 v 1.8).</strike> Next we compare `item[1][1]` to `a[i][1][1]` (3 v 1).  If `item` is `<=` we  can `append.item`, if `item` is `>` we append the comparing set `append(a[i])`.

Updated: Noticed you wanted to compare `item[1]` of last set not actually the first item of the last set.

Also please do consider that this solution will compare itself v itself
To bypass this you could add `if item == a[i]: continue`

**Complaints**

<strike>My only issue is with what you are trying to accomplish. When you compare both `>` and `<`. When the first set is tested .4 being less will append it's set, but then when we compare 1.8 and it being greater you append the .4 set again...</strike>

You could modify and add in `if item not in lista` and `if a[i] not in lista` that checks to see if what you are appending already is in `lista`

```
        if item[1][0] <= a[i][1][0]:
            if item not in lista:
                lista.append(item)
        elif item[1][0] > a[i][1][0]:
            if a[i] not in lista:
                lista.append(a[i])
```

<strike>But even still you are always going to `append` the lesser `item` so you might as well just evaluate only `<=` and check for that in `lista` before you `append`</strike>

I was wrong, I forgot that we are appending if it's equal as well, so enjoy hope this solution was what you were looking for!